# C# Working With FullScreen Project

Tags: visual-studio

Hello I'm developing a fullscreen project in C# with VS 2017 PRO. But the problem is that I cant see the complete form in designer. Like when working with 1920*1080 project. Is there something like "CTRL + Mouse scroll down" ?
Thanks for any help.

Comment: what is all form?

Comment: @Amit controls most likely

Comment: You could use 'Auto-Hide- featured to minimize unused panels, and also there is a zoom function (the percentage button on lower left of your designer/coding window).

Comment: Percentage button is just for the coding window

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Visual Studio Windows Forms editor **does not have any zoom functionality** as it is pixel-based, not vector-based.

All you can do is go **full-screen mode** (SHIFT+ALT+ENTER) and/or use a display device with a **higher resolution**.

On the contrary, the WPF editor does have such a functionality as it is vector-based.